# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson despite having the JAR in the Apache server

Tags: java, servlets, gson, classnotfoundexception

Read many posts regarding the same error on Stackoverflow.
But I am still getting the following error (Stacktrace):

```
Jul 31, 2014 3:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet TEST_Authenticate threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at TEST_Authenticate.doGet(TEST_Authenticate.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Line #70 is as follows in my code:

```
out.println(new Gson().toJson(TESTAuthenticate("myemail@mydomain.com")));
```

I am using Netbeans and here is the structure of my project.

[image]

I have included the JARs in my server `lib` folder as shown in the image above.

Someone answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620336/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson) "did you added the jar to the /WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp? ", however, I don't see `lib` folder inside the `WEB-INF` as shown in the image above. I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

Updated New Screenshot showing `gson-2.2.4.jar`

[image]

Comment: Did you check how many tomcat(s) you have in netbeans?

Comment: @MingtaoCraigZhang Under `Services` tab, I see only one `apache tomcat` listed just like the one which is mentioned in the image above. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Why did you ask about multiple tomcats(s). Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used NetBeans but I think you have to make a difference between the internal classpath for the Tomcat engine itself and the classpath of your application. Tomcat separates this so the web applications are not required to use the same versions of libraries Tomcat uses.
Isn't there another way to define a dependency of your project with the gson library ? F.e. using maven dependency and generate the project file.

Second thing I notice: what is the content of the gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar ? does it contains classes or just javadoc html files.

Normally when building the war file (using maven) these dependencies will be added to the WEB-INF/lib folder in the generated .war file.

Comment: That's the reason I added the `gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar` directly inside the `lib` folder of my `apache Tomcat` rather than adding it inside the `Libraries` section of my web project.

Answer to your second question: When I expand `gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar-->com.google.gson`, I see all `HTML` files listed over there,does this makes any difference? May be I need to have classes in there?

Comment: you surely need another jar with the classes. I asume it will have a name like gson-2.2.4.jar

Comment: Hmm, let me see if I can find JAr with classes in it rather than having html files.

Comment: I already had that JAR. I have updated the correct screenshot below the old one in my question. Please take a look. It has all the classes in it. It was the doc JAR that I expanded in my last image.

Comment: if you build the war file, does it contains the gson-2.2.4.jar in its WEB-INF/lib folder ?

Comment: As shown in the image above, there is only `web.xml` inside `Web Pages-->WEB-INF` folder. By saying `if you build war file` are you pointing me
for building the project? Right now, I have `gson-2.2.4.jar` only inside the `Apache Tomcat` as shown in the image above (in highlighted yellow color).
Please let me know if this is what you were referring to. Thanks

Comment: yes I mean building the project. One day you project will be ready and deliver it as a war file to be deployed. This war file must contain all dependant libraries in its WEB-INF/lib folder and nowhere else.

Comment: Extra tip: you don't have to add a *-javadoc.jar or *-sources.jar to your classpath. It will not be used at runtime and only makes your war file bigger.

Comment: @Coffusion Thanks for the extra tip. I haven't build any `war` file as of yet because I am still figuring out the errors.  I just have been using "Clean and Build" option in Netbeans just to make sure everything runs well at the time of deployment.